# Trying to create Array Item on Mongo document

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a document and want to create the following Array item :

```
MyList:Array
  0:Object
     id : myID
     description : myDescription
```

So when I do this:

```
var obj=db.collections.findOne({name:"MyDocument"});
```

And then

```
obj.MyList.push({id:"myID", description:"myDescription"});
```

I get

```
uncaught exception: TypeError: obj.MyList is undefined
```

I can't figure out how to create MyList first.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception itself :

```
uncaught exception: TypeError: obj.MyList is undefined
```

You need to do define `MyList` :

```
let obj=db.collections.findOne({name:"MyDocument"});
// As MyList is not present in obj
obj.MyList = [];
obj.MyList.push({id:"myID", description:"myDescription"});
```

Or in one DB call, you can push a new array or update existing array with new values :

```
var newArrValues = {id:"myID", description:"myDescription"};
db.getCollection('colletions').updateOne({name:"MyDocument"}, {$push : {MyList :newArrValues}})
```

Based upon scenario you can pick one from here : [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html#examples) (push new values), [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) (replace array with new array), [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/index.html) (Push unique values), there are couple of ways to operate on arrays, Please have a look at documentation.

Comment: yea I knew I had to define it just not sure how, that looks good and I think I have seen $set used for that. Will try that.

Comment: @user2568374 : Yes, you can use either one of those but just test it prior to putting it in code as each one has different features works different based on req, `$set` would replace array in document with new input array.Let me know if there are any issues..

Comment: Yes and I was trying to save" c:\aas\aaa\"  and $set didn't handle '\' If I did '\\' it put them in double.

Comment: @user2568374 : Can you give me the query you're trying & also the specific document you're trying it..!!